# How to find the shortest consecutive substring which contains certain characters in a string in python?

Tags: python, regex, substring

I have a high school competition in coding tomorrow, and while practicing I found many problems where this is asked from me.

Specifically, in this certain task, you have a string which contains numbers that **can** range from 1 to *K*. Let's say *K* is 4, the string could be `1234`, `1222231`, `124123143`, `1311233114`, or anything like that.

I am asked to find the length of the shortest consecutive substring which contains all the values from 1 to *K*. If such a substring doesn't exist, I am supposed to return `-1`.

In case I didn't explain clear enough, if the string was `1234`, the shortest substring would be `1234` and its length is 4. If it was `1222231`, there isn't a number 4 in there, so it should return `-1`. In `124123143` the shortest length is also 4 (`4123`, `2314`), and in the case it was `1311233114`, the shortest length would be 6 - `233114`.

What would be the best (or easiest) way to find this out?

Comment: This seems to contain some relevant information: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9761346/3688648

Answer (score 0):

For k=4 you can do something like this

```
(?=([1234])(?!\1)([1234])(?!\1|\2)([1234])(?!\1|\2|\3)([1234]))
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uN5aG9/1